# Retrieve data from Firebase based on information

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am new to Android developing and Firebase. I have a database where I store info about employees (ex. name, division etc.) I want to create a "login system" in which I introduce for example a name, and based on the data I've written, on a different screen it will only retrieve the data of that employee. Haven't tried anything so far, because I don't know where to start, I only know the basic send/retrieve data to Firebase. I don't ask for a solution, I ask for an idea, something that can help me document myself to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to create a "login system" in which I introduce for example a name

If you want a "login system" for your users, I recommend you [authenticate them with Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth). You can choose between different types of authentication. You can choose to implement email and password authentication or with one of the existing providers, like Google, Facebook, Twitter, and so on. Besides the data that you get from the authentication process, more precisely from [FirebaseUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser) object, you can also add additional information in the database yourself, like name, gender, and so on.

A recommended schema for storing this data in Firebase Realtime Database might be:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- users
       |
       --- $uid
            |
            --- name: "Emanuel"
            |
            --- gender: "male"
            |
            --- email: "emanuel@gmail.com"
            |
            --- age: 25"
```

Below is the official documentation on how to write data to the database:

> https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#basic_write

In short, to read the data only of a specific user, you should create a reference that points to the UID node and attach a listener, like in the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users");
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child(uid);
uidRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            String name = task.getResult().child("name").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", name);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the in depth information. It will help a lot.

Comment: Good to hear that. You're very welcome, Emanuel!